# Can connect Windows computer to network, not OS X?

Tags: internet, isp

I moved back in to my college apartment with some crappy ISP. Last spring, I had no problems, but now, my Macbook can connect to the network just fine when booted into Windows, but can't in OS X.

In Windows, it gets a 10.1.x.x IP, in OS X, just a 192.168.x.x address. The same goes for the default gateway- in Windows, 10.1.x.x, in OS X, 192.168.x.x. So it seems like OS X is not detecting network configuration correctly or something. Is there some way I can give it hints but still let the network assign me an IP address? Or any other ideas?

I've had to call the ISP's support multiple times in the past and it is always an excruciating experience so I'm hoping I can fix this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours, it started working. I changed nothing.

Weird problem- my friends' macbooks had the same issue as mine in OS X, my friends' windows PCs worked fine, and I had the problem described above. Whatever. I hate this ISP so bad.

Answer (score 0):

No. If OS X is getting a 169.x.x.x address, it's not working. 192.168.x.x means there's a DHCP router giving out IP addresses, or it's statically assigned.

So check Windows to see if it's statically assigned or DHCP. Then copy those settings to OS X.

Comment: They are both using DHCP. Default everything.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that one network would give you 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x depending on your operating system. Have you checked your router?

Comment: I agree :P. My iPod Touch has never been able to connect to the network in the past, and the ISP basically told me to shove it. Same result whether connected to the wireless router or plugged into the wall. (I don't have a modem in my apartment, it's a shared connection across the building I guess)